# unique "key" props warning in nextJs not resolving after giving unique key to JSX element

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am making a nextJS app and i am rendering multiple components using map(). but i am giving a unique key to every component in the loop but still getting the error message

[image: pic]

my array of object through which i am looping through

```
const gg = [
    {
      id: "0Lxs4a8cn8pmJ2QLpAJJ",
      phone: "03356210555",
      address: "INSIDE KABLI GATE GUJRAT",
      title: "USAMA FROM PAKISTAN",
      name: "USAMA .AR",
      fax: "2212",
      auctionPOS: "18221",
      auctionName: "PAK AUC",
    },
    {
      id: "XPsusA0fBskQR6hBubpg",
      title: "MALIK SARWAR FROM MALIK TRADING",
      fax: "03356210555",
      address: "INSIDE KABLI GATE GUJRAT",
      auctionPOS: "9318",
      name: "MALIK SARWAR",
      auctionName: "OMAYA",
      phone: "03356210555",
    },
  ];
```

and my JSX code

```
{gg.map((customer) => (
      <>
        <p key={customer.id}> {customer.phone} </p>
      </>
    ))}
```

- As you can see `customer.id` is been used for unique key props
- Solution of the problem i want is "how to resolve the issue of unique key props after giving the unique key to component/JSX element"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The immediate children in the map return must be given unique key

```
{gg.map((customer) => (
       <p key={customer.id}> {customer.phone} </p>
    ))}
```